# Issue with Java and StringIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, string

I am trying to do a school assignment and I am a bit stuck with my code, when I run the code I get this:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: begin 0, end -1, length 25
    at java.base/java.lang.String.checkBoundsBeginEnd(String.java:3756)
    at java.base/java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1902)
    at Demo4/d4.StringBuilder.poistaEkaSana(StringBuilder.java:32)
    at Demo4/d4.StringBuilder.main(StringBuilder.java:18)
```

The goal is to use StringBuilder to remove first name firstname and print characters after space.
Any help is appreciated.

```
import fi.jyu.mit.ohj2.*;

public class StringBuilder {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String nimi = Syotto.kysy("Give Lastname Firstname");
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        removeFirstWord(sb);

        System.out.println("Your last name is " + sb);
        String lastname = giveFirstWord(name);
        System.out.println("Your last name is " + lastname);
    }


    public static String removeFirstWord(StringBuilder sb) {
        String bs = sb.toString();
        int remove= bs.indexOf(" ");
        String second= bs.substring(0, remove);
        return second;

    }

    public static String giveFirstWord(String fname) {
        int s1= fname.indexOf(' ');
        String d2= fname.substring(s1, 14);
        return d2;
    }
}
```

Comment: How can you remove anything from an empty stringbuilder?

Comment: Note that if your intent was to use `java.lang.StringBuilder` you shadowed it by naming your own class StringBuilder.

Comment: Your problem has exactly nothing to do with `StringBuilder`, apart from it being empty, or return-values.

Answer (score 0):

Your class name is confusing with `java.lang.StringBuilder`.

Rename your class name( or use FQCN), and

```java
    String nimi = Syotto.kysy("Give Lastname Firstname");
    java.lang.StringBuilder sb = new java.lang.StringBuilder(nimi); // add argument
```